# How to store a list or a number into empty array in jsl?

Tags: sas-jmp, jsl

I face a problem on how to store a list or a number into an empty array, below is my code :

```
    For( i = 1, i <= N Items( S ), i++,
    dt:Family Device << set name( "family device" );
    dt << Select Where(Starts With( dt:family device, S[i] ) ) ;
    baseDT = dt << Subset( output table name( "Subset" ), selected rows( 1 ), selected columns( 0 ), "invisible");
```

I plan to store baseDT in the empty array, Anyone has an idea on the store function? I very new to JSL if in python we will use append function to store, then how about jsl?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an empty array as

```
emp_array = {};
```

Append to array as :

```
Insert Into(emp_array, baseDT)
```

Then you can access the elements using index eg:

```
emp_array[n]
```